# Minimum Probability on a Finite Alphabet

Tags: probability, statistics, applications

Let $K$ be a finite (but very large) positive integer. Let $P=\{p_{k};k=1,\cdots,K\}$ be a probability distribution on an alphabet $\mathscr{X}=\{\ell_{k}; k=1,\cdots,K\}$. Let $p_{\wedge}=\min \{p_{k}\}$. Can anyone please tell me how $p_{\wedge}$ is related to a practical problem, or how knowing $p_{\wedge}$ (or estimating it) is of practical interest in some scientific context (physics, information theory, security, etc.)?

The reason I ask this question is that I think I have a good way of estimating $p_{\wedge}$ (non-parametrically) but could not think of a motivating context.

In fact, I could not even find literature references on estimating minimum probability. If you have any idea on references to this problem, please share - I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean you are estimating the minimum of a list of values when the sum of the values is 1?

Comment: Yes, the minimum of a list of POSITIVE values adding up to 1. But I am not asking how to do that, just for motivating scenarios.

Comment: How about, you want to start an insurance company to complete with Lloyds, selling bets on rare outcomes.  If you issue a policy for an event with probability $p$ your payout might be on the order $1/p$.  To help figure out how much money you need from backers, you might want to know the probability of the most unlikely event.

Comment: @kimchi lover, hmm, that is something ... need more, anything related to Statistical Learning and Artificial Intelligence? It certainly ``feels'' as if there should be a relationship ...